# WinForms. Как привязать выполнение некоторого метода к выбору элементов в comboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется форма с выпадающим меню (comboBox). Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы при выборе какого-нибудь значения в выпадающем меню выполнялся некоторый метод, с выбранным значением в качестве атрибута?

Например, выбираю в меню "Москва" и после этого выполняется MyMethod("Москва").

Comment: Не понятно в чем проблема

Comment: Сейчас перепишу вопрос.

Comment: Так подпишитесь на событие https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не спец в WinForms, но у комбобокса есть событие [`SelectedValueChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Так что скорее всего вам надо

```
combobox.SelectedValueChanged += (o, args) => MyMethod(combobox.SelectedValue);
```

---

Обновление: как подсказывает @InfernumDeus в комментариях, нужно использовать `Text` вместо `SelectedValue`.

```
combobox.SelectedValueChanged += (o, args) => MyMethod(combobox.Text);
```

Comment: Не понял, куда вставлять эту строку. В любом случае, теперь ясно, что следует искать. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, это та точка, где вы подписываетесь на изменения. Наверное, при создании формы?

Comment: Да, в таком случае работает. Только метод, почему-то получает null. Посмотрю документацию на combobox.

Comment: @InfernumDeus: Ну, если в комбобоксе _ничего_ не выбрано, то `combobox.SelectedValue` наверное `null`.

Comment: Всё, понял, методу следует передавать comboBox1.Text. Теперь идеально.

Comment: SelectedValue для него не работает, так как combobox не имеет свойства ValueMember. Вместо этого у него Text.

Comment: @InfernumDeus: Спасибо! Обновил ответ.